# Workflow Foundation: how to implement queueing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation-4

I have implemented WF in my web aplication and it is working async. Here is example

```
    public Guid Something(string somVar)
    {
            WorkflowApplication i = new WorkflowApplication(SomeWF.Some(somVar));
            SetupWorkflowCallbacks(ref i);
            i.Run();
            return i.Id;

    }
```

Now problem starts when I need to call one external api that can only recive one request for user. For example 10 web page users can run this WF and everything will be ok. But when one user run  WF 2 times in short period time I am reciving error from api. 
I would need some sort of Queuing to avoid this type of error.

Comment: If memory serves you can do this with a correlation token. See if that helps?

Comment: can something be done with ManualResetEvent. I would put .WaitOne(); and when is web service called I could call .Set() but that doesnt seam safe.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the workflow starts + completes in the same process, especially if hosted in AppFabric.

Comment: I took another aproach. I allready have WF persisted in DB. So what I did was start WF and pot it to into sleep. The I send his proces ID to  queu with help of MSMQ.